# T4 Template used in Dapper.SimpleCRUD.ModelGenerator truncated a table name

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, dapper, t4

I am using this nuget package: [Dapper.SimpleCRUD.ModelGenerator](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Dapper.SimpleCRUD.ModelGenerator/) which is based on this [T4 template](https://github.com/ericdc1/Dapper.SimpleCRUD/blob/master/Dapper.SimpleCRUD.ModelGenerator/Content/Models/ModelGenerator.tt.pp).

It works great!  But there is one small problem.  This table:

```
/// <summary>
/// A class which represents the CurrentStatus table.
/// </summary>
[Table("CurrentStatus")]
public partial class CurrentStatu
{
    ...
}
```

The table `CurrentStatus` was generated as `CurrentStatu`.  I've not yet looked over the entire list of tables, but there may be others?

I would assume this is some sort of setting in the template to make table names singular or plural, but I'm not finding it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I found a way to fix this. It was indeed trying to singularize table names. I commented out line 518 of the template and added line 519:

```
//tbl.ClassName=Singularize(RemoveTablePrefixes(tbl.CleanName));
tbl.ClassName=RemoveTablePrefixes(tbl.CleanName);
```

**EDIT:**

I actually ended up more deeply modifying the template to have the option to exempt certain tables from being singularized.